# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value') - React Input OnChange Function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input, onchange

I have an input defined using the following code:

```
<Form.Field required>
                            <label>
                                {intl.formatMessage({
                                    id: 'name_label',
                                    defaultMessage: 'Venue Name',
                                })}
                            </label>
                            <input
                                autoComplete="off"
                                placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
                                    id: 'name_label',
                                    defaultMessage: 'Venue Name',
                                })}
                                onChange={handleChange('name')}
                                defaultValue={name}
                            />
                        </Form.Field>
```

The on change function is defined as follows:

```
 const [values, setValues] = useState({
        name: '',
        phoneNo: '',
        city: '',
        country: '',
        postcode: '',
        address: '',
    });

 const handleChange = input => e => {
        setValues(v => ({ ...v, [input]: e.target.value.trim() }));
    };
```

I'm getting an error: `TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'value')` if I hit backspace and `name` is defined - if I type additional characters into the `input` the code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
onChange={handleChange('name')}
should be 
onChange={handleChange}
```

and modify

```
const handleChange =  e => {
        setValues(v => ({ ...v, e.target.customAttributeName: e.target.value.trim() }));
    };
```

customAttributeName you can define like this

```
<input
                            autoComplete="off"
                            placeholder={intl.formatMessage({
                                id: 'name_label',
                                defaultMessage: 'Venue Name',
                            })}
                            onChange={handleChange}
                            defaultValue={name}
                            customAttributeName="name"
                        />
```